# XSLT mapping to remove parent element when Child is empty or missing

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to remove E1EDPT1 element if all TDLINE tag is empty or doesn't exists. I tried with  but didn't work.

```
    <E1EDPT1 SEGMENT="">
    <TDID>Z014</TDID>
    <TSSPRAS>EN</TSSPRAS>
   </E1EDPT1>
   <E1EDPT1 SEGMENT="">
    <TDID>Z002</TDID>
    <TSSPRAS>EN</TSSPRAS>
   </E1EDPT1>
   <E1EDPT1 SEGMENT="">
    <TDID>Z012</TDID>
    <TSSPRAS>EN</TSSPRAS>
   </E1EDPT1>
   <E1EDPT1 SEGMENT="">
    <TDID>Z011</TDID>
    <TSSPRAS>EN</TSSPRAS>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="">
        <TDLINE></TDLINE>
        <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="">
    <TDLINE>Hello</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
     </E1EDPT1>
```

Output should look like below.

```
   <E1EDPT1 SEGMENT="">
    <TDID>Z011</TDID>
    <TSSPRAS>EN</TSSPRAS>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="">
       <TDLINE>Hello</TDLINE>
       <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
   </E1EDPT1>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Mohan

Comment: Add what you tried to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your required output, I think you do not need to delete the entire `E1EDPT1` node if it's child or descendant is empty.

Try the stylesheet below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- delete E1EDPT1 node if it has an empty TDLINE child 
        or if it does not have any descendant TDLINE -->
    <xsl:template match="E1EDPT1[TDLINE = '' or (count(descendant::TDLINE[. != '']) = 0)]"/>

    <xsl:template match="E1EDPT2[TDLINE = '' or not(TDLINE)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But the above rule didn't remove parent(E1EDPT1) segment when both children(E1EDPT2 -->TDLINE)   were empty.           <E1EDPT1 SEGMENT="">
            <TDID>Z011</TDID>
            <TSSPRAS>EN</TSSPRAS>
            <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="">
               <TDLINE/>
               <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
            </E1EDPT2>
            <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="">
               <TDLINE/>
               <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
            </E1EDPT2>
         </E1EDPT1>

Comment: Thank you very much Joel for your help, it worked like a charm.